# Is there a formula I can use which when i drag automatically references +5 columns each time?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to reference cells A1, then + 5 columns so F1, then + another 5 columns K1, and so on......
Is there a formula I can use which when i drag automatically references +5 columns each time?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this easily.

1. Create your first reference in `F1` by typing `=A1`.
2. Highlight `B1` to `F1`.
3. Click and hold the lower right corner of the selected cells, then drag the handle over the number of cells you want.
4. This will copy the reference into every 5th cell.

If you want all cells to absolutely reference `A1`, use `=$A$1` in cell `F1` before you copy it across.

[image]